# How can I locate database in xampp path?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I have changed my windows and I forgot to export from local databases
fortunately I have installed xampp on another partition which windows is not installed on that,

in new windows previous xampp didn't start and I have installed it again
Just I don't know how can I copy my databases (which I haven't backup and I don't have .sql file) in previous xampp to this version I have recently installed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

say the old version of xampp on `C` partition, so go this path `C:\xampp\mysql\data` and copy all databases folders, then you should install the same old version of xampp on your machine to avoid the problems and errors with different versions then paste all folders in the `data` folder of the installed xampp and start your mysql server you will find all your databases and you can export them as you like.